# show/hide content of partial view dynamically based on button click in main view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to show/hide  content from partial view dynamically based on `Select` button click in main view.

1. If I click on `Catalogue Style Unedited` in main view, then from the
   `partial` view, the `Horse` (1st) radio button should be selected along with
   1st textbox and the rest content will be hidden.
2. If I click on `Internet Pedigree` in main view the `Dam` (2nd) radio
   button with 2nd textbox will be visible and the and the rest content will be hidden.
3. If I click on `Research Document` in main view the `Theoretical`
   (3rd) radio button will be selected and both textboxes will be
   visible

My `model`:

```
public class ClsTest
{        
    public int HorseId { get; set; }
    public string Horse { get; set; }
    public int DamId { get; set; }
    public string Dam { get; set; }
    public int TheoreticalId { get; set; }
    public string Theoretical { get; set; }  
}
```

my `main` View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Test.Website.Models.ClsTest>
<table id="tblTest">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ProductName)</th>
        ....
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)</td>
            ....
            <td>
                <input class="search btn-default" type="button" value="Select" data-assigned-id="@item.ProductCode" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function() {
        $('#Partial').on('change', '.AddContainer input[type="radio"]', function()  {     
            var divs = $('.Add1').find('.container');
            var id = $(this).data('divid');
            divs.hide(); 
            $('#' + id).show();
        });

        $('.search').click(function () {
            var id = $(this).data('assigned-id');
            var route = '@Url.Action("DisplayPartialView", "Home")?id=' + id;
            $('#Partial').load(route);
        });
    });
</script>
```

My `JavaScript`:

My `main view Image`:
[image]
 My `partial` view:

```
<div class="AddContainer">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="Service" value="false" data-divid="A" checked />
            <span>Horse</span>
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="Service" value="true" data-divid="B" />
            <span>Dam</span>
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="Service" value="true" data-divid="C" />
            <span>Theoretical</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Add1">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div id="A" class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
                {
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Horse, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(n => n.Horse) })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.HorseId)
                    <input type="button" value="Search" class="btn btn-default active" />
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="B" class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Dam, new { @class = "form-control", 
                 placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(n => n.Dam) })
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DamId)
                <input type="button" value="Search" class="btn btn-default 
                   active" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="submit" value="Produce Page" class="btn btn-default 
             active" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can we achieve this? Anyone please guide me if we can then. Thank you.

Comment: You have not explained what is working and what is not working (and scripts should never be in partials (move it to the main view, and you will need to use event delegation because you dynamically loading the partial)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Actually this is my code and I do not have any idea how to use event delegation. The code is working fine but I need to load dynamically. It will be appreciated if you could create a demo for this so that I can reference from there.So please create it in your free time. Thank you for your help as always.

Comment: You still have not explained what the issue is. Is the partial loading when you click the 'Select' button? But I assume its the 2nd script that is not working for you because (1) it should be in the main view, not the partial, and (2) you need to use `$('#Partial').on('change', '.AddContainer input[type="radio"]', function() { ....` (refer [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/))

Comment: @StephenMuecke, partial is loading when I click `select` button. And even 2nd script is also working. There is no issues in the code as it is working for me but i want to display the partial view content based on button click dynamically. So I am requesting you to provide some sample solutions so that I can reference.

Comment: Again, scripts should NEVER be in partials! And you need to explain the issue in the question, not comments (I still do not understand what it is)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I changed the question and added `<script>` into `main` view. Please have a look and assist me. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163023/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-raj).